# PayPal Express Checkout - friends or family

Tags: paypal

Hello I have a paypal payment gateway like to set the payment was sent as friends or family, not as goods or services, how to set up?

```
<form name="paypalform" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?=$site['paypal']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?='Add Funds - '.$data['login'].' - '.$s_host['host']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=($data['id'].'|'.$cash.'|'.VisitorIP())?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$cash?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?=($site['currency_code'] == '' ? 'USD' : $site['currency_code'])?>">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?=$site['site_url']?>/bank.php?success">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?=$site['site_url']?>/bank.php?cancel">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?=$site['site_url']?>/system/payments/paypal/ipn.php">
</form>
```

Comment: You can use [PayPal.me](https://www.paypal.me) or have your friends and family send you money also.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not something you can code your button to do, since the choice is only presented to a PayPal account holder during the "Send Money" process.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done using the Adaptive Payments API.  You'll setup a Pay request and you'll see the payment type to PERSONAL.  More details available in the [Pay API request doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

So you can't do it with a basic button like you're showing here, but if you can handle API calls you can get it done that way (assuming PayPal approves your app).